# How do I prove that a given set is an affine space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, affine-geometry

[image]

Let $A$ be an affine space over a vector space $V$. Let $B$ be a nonempty subset of $A$ such that $W:=\{a-b\in V:a,b\in B\}$ is a subspace of $V$. In this case, how do I prove that for each $b\in B$ and $y\in W$, $b+y\in B$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong, hence you can't prove it :-)

As an example choose
$A=V=\mathbb{R}^2$
and $B:=\{(x,y) \ | \ x=0 \lor y=0\}$
as the union of the two axes. You can easily see, that $W=\mathbb{R}^2$ holds (for $v=(x,y)\in V$ take $a=(x,0)$ and $b=(0,-y)$). But obviously $B$ is not an affine space. E.g. $(0,0)+(1,1) =(1,1)\notin B$ but $(0,0) \in B$ and $(1,1) \in W$.

Comment: Then, wikipedia gives a wrong definition of affine subspace. What would be a correct definition of affine subspace? Should it be a nonempty subset $B\subset A$ such that$ that $B$ is **an affine space over $W$**?

Comment: @Rubertos Yes. It is a (some say nonempty, this varies depending on your source) subset, which is itself an affine space.

Comment: It's the first time I see wikipedia is totally wrong.. Really surprising. Thank you.

Comment: @Rubertos No problem. I mentioned it in the wiki discussion page (since I am not actually active there, I refrain from changing it directly). You might think of the wikidefinition the right way, if you keep track of all the differences (starting and ending point) and see if this is a vector space (much bigger than the translation space) but that would be kindof horrible. The wikis definition is at least strongly misleading. You should stick with the is itself an affine space (which is the correct definition).

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is itself an affine space of $V$ *and* a subset of $A$, then we get the desired conclusion.

Since $A$ is an affine space of $V$, there exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ and a vector $v$ in $V$ such that $A = v + U = \{v + u:u \in U\}.$ Since $B$ is also affine and a subset of $A$, there exists a subspace $U'$ of $U$ such that $B = v + U' = \{v + u':u \in U'\}$. Let $a, b \in B$. Then, there exist $x_a,x_b \in U'$ such that
$$
a = v + x_a \\
b = v + x_b.
$$
If $y \in W$, there exist $a,b \in B$ such that $y = a - b = (v + x_a) - (v + x_b) = x_a - x_b \in U'$. Let $b = v + x_b' \in B$. Then,
$$
b + y = v + x_b' + (x_a - x_b) = v + (x_b' + x_a - x_b).
$$
$U'$ is a subspace of $V$, so $U'$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Furthermore, $x_b',x_a,x_b\in U'$. Hence, $(x_b'+x_a-x_b) \in U'$, so $v + (x_b' + x_a - x_b)\in B$.

Comment: Why should $v + (x_b' + x_a - x_b)\in B$ hold? $B$ is just a subset of $A$. It just hold $v + (x_b' + x_a - x_b)\in A$!

Comment: @ctst I edited my post to fix this. It's true that a subset alone won't work. Instead, $B$ has to be an affine space as well.

Comment: @Rubertos I edited my answer to show how you can prove the statement in the case that $B$ is also an affine space.

Comment: @AOrtiz I'm confused now. So is an affine subspace required to be an affine space over $V$ or $W$? Do you mean $W$ instead of $V$?

Comment: @Rubertos The statement is that the affine spaces we are considering are all affine spaces over $V$.

Comment: @Rubertos I edited my answer to be more transparent in the case that the set $B$ is also an affine space over $V$.

Comment: @AOrtiz I'm not sure how that makes sense. Let $+:A\times V\rightarrow A$ be an addition satisfying affine space axioms. To say that $B$ is an affine space in a natural sense over $V$ is that the restriction map $+:B\times V\rightarrow B$ satisfies affine space axioms. To say that $B$ is an affine space in a natural sense over $W$ is that the restriction map $+:B\times W\rightarrow B$ satisfies affine space axioms. If you are assuming any of these cases, your proof does not mean a thing.. Beyond all, the first case does not make sense, [continued..]

Comment: @Rubertos I am using the definition of what it means for a set $S$ to be an affine subset of a vector space $V$. A set $S$ is an affine subset of a vector space $V$ if there exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ and a vector $v \in V$ such that $S = v + U = \{v + u: u \in U\}$.

Comment: because since $A$ is an affine space, $V\rightarrow A:v\mapsto a+v$ for a fixed $a\in B$ is a bijection. Hence if you require $B$ to be an affine space over $V$, then $V\rightarrow B:v\mapsto a+v$ is also a bijection, which forces $B$ to be $A$. So it does not make sense..